# Emergency mode after installing new CPU and changing RAM configuration

Tags: server, 16.04

Dual Intel® Socket 2011-3/ Intel C612 PCH chipset
*Streamlined-airflow design with 16 DIMM slots
*Enhanced parallel GPU computing power with six PCI Express 3.0 x16 slots
*Supreme Power Solution – Premium components deliver industry-leading power efficiency
*Complete remote server management with IPMI 2.0-compliant ASMB8-iKVM module and ASWM Enterprise motherboard.

A new CPU QH26 was installed.

I have switched from a 8x16 GB CPU1 RAM config to a 4x16 GB CPU1 RAM and 4x16 GB CPU2 RAM configuration.

I am getting long boot times and this error message:

```
[   0.141051] DMAR-IR: [Firmware Bug]: icapic 3 no mapping icmnu, interrupt
remapping will be disabled
[   11.172656] power_meter ACPI0000:00: Ignoring unsafe software power cap!
Welcome to emergency mode! After logging in, type "hournalctl -xb" to view
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or ^D to
try again to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue):
```

When I revert back to my original state of working condition it boots normal and fast.

Am I overkilling or does my kernel not yet support this configuration?

EDIT: I Also have a SSD inside the computer. When I removed it and reverted back to my original settings it boots, I powered down and added the SSD again and was presented with the same message.

Comment: Im no expert but from reading the logs it would seem that yes, your hardware could be rather "overkill," due to a - quote - `unsafe software power cap!` but then again it could be something different.

Comment: It seems to be the SSD that caused all the ruckus; I am attempting to Gpart the drive from CD and attempt another boot.

Comment: Can you copy the text from that screenshot into your question?  The screenshot is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a BIOS bug.

`[Firmware Bug]: icapic 3 no mapping icmnu, interrupt remapping will be disabled`

This system's ACPI tables did not indicate which iommu serviced ioapic number 3 in your machine.  Without an iommu, interrupt remapping can't work, and so it is being disabled.  Update your bios to fix this issue.

Also it's not icmnun but rather **iommu** as in
[Input–output memory management unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input%E2%80%93output_memory_management_unit).

You can try disabling **apic** (not **ACPI**) as explained [here](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/APIC).

You can try to move around your memory sticks to see if the ioapic number changes, if so it may indicate a possible memory and/or memory controller issue.

Comment: I am going to attempt this.